# When submiting form in codeception acceptance test auth breaks

Tags: laravel, codeception

I am writing codecept acceptance test in laravel 4.2 and I am having problem with the following code:

```
$I->authenticateUserByEmail($I, 'pera@lozac.com');
$I->amOnPage('/admin/offer/create-specijalna-ponuda');
$I->fillField('input[name=offer_name]', 'My Offer');
$I->attachFile('input[name=offer_image]', $I->getSpecPonudaImageSport1());
$I->selectOption('form select[name=offer_brand]', 1);
$I->click('Submit');
//$I->see('Success: Offer My Offer created.');
```

`authenticateUserByEmail()` is doing following:

```
$user = \User::where('email','=',$email)->first();  
$I->amLoggedAs($user);
```

All works fine until submit button is clicked. When that line is present I am receiving following error inside controller that handles this post method:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function hasSupplier() on a non-object
```

This is a line where the error occurs:

```
$this->isUserSupplier = Auth::user()->hasSupplier();
```

If I put this line immediatelly before:

```
dd(Auth::user()->hasSupplier());
```

this is printend in the console:

```
bool(false)
```

Anyway when this line removed error "`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function hasSupplier() on a non-object`" remains.

I am using [Zizaco Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)  package for role based permissions. Here is my User class:

```
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUserInterface;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;
class User extends Eloquent implements ConfideUserInterface
{

    use ConfideUser;
    use HasRole;

    public function supplier(){
        return $this->hasOne('Supplier', 'id', 'supplier_id');
    }

    public function hasSupplier(){
        $supplier = $this->supplier;
        return !is_null($supplier);
    }

}
```

If I put following line inside controller immediately before error line to check user:

```
dd(Auth::user());
```

this is printend into console:

```
object(User)#13077 (21) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["table":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["username"]=>
    string(6) "pera"
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "pera@lozac.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$zAOANTPOjW7BBA010i3TrexBe23nhEuQnlK0h/Y1m1XVD8kCaEIEC"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Pera"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(9) "Lozac"
    ["phone"]=>
    NULL
    ["address"]=>
    NULL
    ["age"]=>
    NULL
    ["active"]=>
    int(1)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["notify"]=>
    int(1)
    ["remember_token"]=>
    string(60) "g6S5hjtz7TbEB96DBmBZjaBNTZfmtKaV4zObY3TssDSFxaHnL98myqzfebmU"
    ["confirmation_code"]=>
    string(32) "fd5a00cd497c2bf5be6f4df48fb49719"
    ["confirmed"]=>
    int(0)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-30 13:31:46"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-30 22:37:19"
    ["supplier_id"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["username"]=>
    string(6) "pera"
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "pera@lozac.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$zAOANTPOjW7BBA010i3TrexBe23nhEuQnlK0h/Y1m1XVD8kCaEIEC"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Pera"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(9) "Lozac"
    ["phone"]=>
    NULL
    ["address"]=>
    NULL
    ["age"]=>
    NULL
    ["active"]=>
    int(1)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["notify"]=>
    int(1)
    ["remember_token"]=>
    string(60) "g6S5hjtz7TbEB96DBmBZjaBNTZfmtKaV4zObY3TssDSFxaHnL98myqzfebmU"
    ["confirmation_code"]=>
    string(32) "fd5a00cd497c2bf5be6f4df48fb49719"
    ["confirmed"]=>
    int(0)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-30 13:31:46"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-30 22:37:19"
    ["supplier_id"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["morphClass":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["errors"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Form submition breaks something. Any idea how to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume the user is logged in,before you call `hasSupplier()` make sure that `Auth::user()` didn't return NULL/false

instead of

`$this->isUserSupplier = Auth::user()->hasSupplier();`

do

`$this->isUserSupplier = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->hasSupplier() : false;`

are you sure that the email you check against exists in the database ?
could you `dd($user)`?

Comment: I have edited question with required info. User exists but connection is NULL and table is null.

Comment: and if you do `dd(Auth::user())` what do you get ?

Comment: just noticed you mentioned that the error remains even when you remove the call,this means that the error doesn't come from this line,you have somewhere else in your code a call to `hasSupplier` on a non object variable.

Comment: this code works ok when run from browser. Within codception context auth and all other tests works until submit form. Then breaks. Seems that submit form logs out user somehow.

Comment: if you add call to `authenticateUserByEmail` again right after the submit it works fine?

Comment: No, because it dies in submit. This is the flow:
1. Auth
2. Open url and first time enter in controller  
3. Submit  
4. Second time in controller. This time is no authenticated and throws error